# Angular 9 and Storybook: Add @angular/localize/init polyfill

Tags: angular, storybook, angular9

When updating to angular 9 I get the following Storybook error.

[Error message from storybook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcwyn.png)

The error says that I need to add a polyfill for internationalization, but I can't figure out how to.

I need to configure webpack and add the polyfill there, but I am not able to get it to work.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Cheers

EDIT:
To clarify I did I ran the `ng add @angular/localize` in the angular project.

Nevertheless, Storybook is not picking it up.

This is my polyfills.ts file.

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Load `$localize` onto the global scope - used if i18n tags appear in Angular templates.
 */
import '@angular/localize/init';
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es/reflect';

/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
/* https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/678 fix: */
(window as any).global = window;
/* https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/678 fix end */
```

EDIT2:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../src/tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "../src/test.ts",
    "../src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "../projects/**/*.spec.ts",
    "../src/assets/webgl_2019_1/**/*"
  ],
  "include": [
    "../src/**/*",
    "../projects/**/*"
  ],
  "files": [
    "./typings.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your error `literally` states: `Please run ng add @angular/localize from the Angular CLI.`

Comment: @Carsten I did do this in my Angular Application. But this is an error from storybook

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**TLDR:** Adding `import '@angular/localize/init';` into `config.js` or `preview.js` in the .storybook folder.

**Explanation**

The issue is that Storybook can't find the polyfill `@angular/localize/init`. Since Storybook uses webpack to serve Storybook we need to add the polyfill to webpack.

Adding a polyfill to webpack can be done by adding it to the `entries` array. https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/

By looking at this page (https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/) you can figure out how to configure storybook to add your polyfill. There is a header here called `This is what the config for storybook looks like when using CRA in dev-mode:`

If you expand this it shows the default configurations of webpack in storybook. In the entries array, you can see that there is the following line:
`'<your-storybook-dir>/preview.js'`. If you add the polyfill in this file it will be to webpack aswell.

`preview.js` and `config.js` are treated as the same file so adding the polyfill to either one of them will do the trick.

Comment: this is the right answer, I had to add the import that you would normally put in the pollyfill files into each of my preview.js storybook file (storybook v6)

Comment: Wow, this comment was super helpful! The error message is quite misleading, because it leads to another solution (which is not working).

Answer (score 1):

You have to install @angular/localize and import '@angular/localize/init' in your polyfills.ts
You can also : ng add @angular/localize  (install and add to polyfill for you)
or
import '@angular/localize/init' into the config.js

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. I did this but for some reason Storybook isn't picking this up.

Comment: Where did you import your polyfill.ts ? I had the same error and I imported the polyfill into main.ts and it worked for me.

Comment: I am not explicitly importing it into Storybook. I believe I have to configure the webpack that Storybook uses to pick up the polyfills. But I can't figure out how... There is some Storybook documentation on how to configure webpack (https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/) but nothing specific

Comment: could you share what your main.ts looks like?

Comment: try to import "./polyfills"; in main.ts

Comment: I get the following error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. That is the only line in the main.ts btw. Don't I need to add some webpack config in the main.ts?

Comment: could you provide your webpack config and tsconfig please

Comment: I added the tsconfig from the .storybook folder in the original post. I didn't have a custom webpack config file at the moment.

Comment: In Angular 9 your tsconfig sould be like https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration with compilerOptions "target": "es2015", "module": "esnext",   "moduleResolution": "node",  "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]

Comment: I will have a look at what you mentioned above. I did find a solution for the polyfill issue. I imported it `import '@angular/localize/init'` into the config.js. This solved the issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I changed my operating system because of this problem. And yesterday I found the cause of this problem. I was getting this issue due to a plugin I installed in Visual Studio Code. If you are using Angular9, do not install the first two plugins. You can install the third one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding in **package.json** this line

```
"dependencies": {
 ...
 "@angular/localize": "^10.2.4",
}
```

then I ran:

```
npm install
```